# How to set Roles claims using Azure AD in Blazor Wasm?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, authorization, claims-based-identity, authorize-attribute

I am using Azure AD authentication for authentication. I using CustomAccountFactory to add custom claims to my idenitity. Here is how the program.cs file looks:

```
    builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState,
      CustomUserAccount>(options =>
      {
          builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
          options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("https://graph.microsoft.com/openid");
          options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "appRole";
      }).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount,
  CustomUserFactory>();
```

Here is how the CustomUserFactory looks like:

```
 public class CustomUserFactory
: AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserAccount>
{
    private readonly ILogger<CustomUserFactory> logger;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory clientFactory;

 
    public IUserService _userService { get; set; }

    public CustomUserFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor,IUserService userService,
        ILogger<CustomUserFactory> logger)
        : base(accessor)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
        CustomUserAccount account,
        RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var initialUser = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (initialUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)initialUser.Identity;

            if (_userService != null)
            {
                var roles = await _userService.GetUserRolesByUserName("UsernameTest").ConfigureAwait(true);

                Console.WriteLine("roles count before: " + roles?.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("claims count before: " + userIdentity.Claims.Count());

                foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                  //  userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.RsecGrpId));

                    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("appRole", role.RsecGrpId));


                }

                Console.WriteLine("roles count after: " + roles?.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("claims count after: " + userIdentity.Claims.Count());

 

            }
            Console.WriteLine("printing claims");
            foreach (var item in userIdentity.Claims)
            {
        
                Console.WriteLine(item?.Value);
                Console.WriteLine(item?.Type);
            }
       
        }

        return initialUser;
    }
}
```

}

Now the roles are added here, However when I use it like in my razor views

```
   @attribute [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
```

It returns False. The roles are added to the claims, as keyvalue pair like, "appRole" : "ADMIN". However it is Roles on the Authorize are not set? Also, it is showing up in the context on any view.

What do I need to do to make sure I get those roles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that in your authorization by roles, you are using the role name however, in your constructor, you are using userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("appRole", role.**RsecGrpId**));.  Without seeing your CustomUserAccount, I am not certain.

Try changing:
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("appRole", role.RsecGrpId));

to

userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("appRole", role));